# how to split a string unknown amount of times, into a list

Tags: python

In morse code: a space " " is written as a slash " / ". A gap between letters is written as a space " ".

I made a English-to-Morse translator. It was easy, since each letter was 1 character long, so I could separate it into characters. However, going the other way is hard. I need to be able to detect splits between letters, but also make sure I am not detecting splits between words.

Here is my python code:

```
print("\nNote: not all characters are logged. \n\n")

english = [ "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p",
            "q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6",
            "7","8","9","0",".",",",";",":","!","?","(",")","-","_","!","&",
            "=","+","$","/","'"," "]

morse = [ ".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",
          ".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",
          ".--","-..-","-.--","--..",".----","..---","...--","....-",".....",
          "-....","--...","---..","----.","-----",".-.-.-","-..-","-.-.-.",
          "---...","--..--","..--..","-.--.","-.--.-","-....-","..--.-","--..--",
          ".-...","-...-",".-.-.","...-..-","-..-.",".----."," /"]





while True:
    print ("English to Morse: press 1 ")
    print ("Morse to English: press 2 ")
    print ("What is morse code: press 3")
    translate_direction = input("\n>").replace(" ","")

                            
    if translate_direction == "1":
    
        tobetranslated = input("\nTranslate English to Morse Code\n\n> ").lower()
        splitupinput = list(tobetranslated)
        finishedoutput = ""

        for i in splitupinput:
            englishloc = english.index(i)
            finishedoutput = finishedoutput + morse[englishloc]
            finishedoutput = finishedoutput + " "    
              
        print(finishedoutput)

    elif translate_direction == "2":

        tobetranslated = input("\nTranslate Morse Code to English\n\n> ").lower()
        tobetranslated = tobetranslated.replace(" ","ß ")
        
        finishedoutput = ""

        for i in splitupinput:
            englishloc = english.index(i)
            finishedoutput = finishedoutput + morse[englishloc]
            finishedoutput = finishedoutput + " "    
              
        print(finishedoutput)

    elif translated_irection == "3":
        print("Morse code is... (insert long-winded explanation of the history of morse code and its applications)")
```

I am using `.replace()` to replace the spaces with some character that is not in morse code plus the space, so that when I split along "π", which will be lost, I have a space left there so that I can determine splits between words.

But, I have an issue: I do not know how to split a string, along an undeterminable amount of splits, into a list.

Any help?

Fun fact: I only have the standard library. Sorry! I am a minor, and my parents aren't willing to download anything, no matter how much I ask.

I also am new to python, so if you could make a quick explanation as to how/why something works, that would be really nice :)

Comment: Is `string.split()` what you want? It will split the string into a list along whatever character(s) you provide.

Comment: Please show your parents this: half a century ago my parents were supportive when I wanted to pursue computer programming. (They gave me rides to a university computer center.) And it gave me a great career.  Downloading python packages is vastly different, and much safer, than downloading most things from the internet. And you will be able to learn a lot, and help create the foundation for YOUR great career. With respect, Ms. and Mr. Tung, please consider more nuanced rules about downloading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the built in `.split()` method.

It does this sort of thing.

```
>>> '1/2/3'.split('/')
['1', '2', '3']
```

Read about it here. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string split function to split the string into a list of strings by a provided delimiter. For example, the following code splits a string by spaces into a string list.

```
stuff_to_split = "Hello there my friend"

list_of_strings = stuff_to_split.split(' ')

for word in list_of_strings:
    print(word)
```

Outputs

```
Hello
there
my
friend
```